# WP upgraded 5.5.1 and get Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 5.5.1 upgraded today and I now get a screen full of messages as below:
CiviCRM is V 5.27.1 and PHP 7.3. Have cleared Civi cache. Any ideas please?

Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 490

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 987

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 988

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 989

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 990

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 991

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 992

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 995

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 996

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 999

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1000

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1001

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1002

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1005

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1006

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1007

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1008

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1011

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1296

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:490) in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1299

Thank you for creating with WordPress.

Version 5.5.1

**Another error**
Users reporting the following error when trying t respond to a petition. Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.
Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.
Error type: Could not find a valid session key.
Return to home page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by clearing CiviCRM Cache `https://yoururl.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1`

I'd also refresh permalinks by visiting `https://yoururl.org//wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

Then double check that you have abase page set here and it is publicly visible `https://yoursiteurl.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1`

Once that is complete, see if you still have any errors.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your suggestions. Have done all these things already and same result with signing petition and then submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

This all related to the session key issue.
Have been able to get over the session key error by installing a fresh install of WP and CiviCRM, then restoring Wordpress and CiviCRM DBs, repointing wp_config.php and CiviCRM.settings.php. Also had to rename my table prefixes in wp_config.php to match my restored tables. The caches get created once you start up CiviCRM and do things. Testing so far all functionality is working again. Hopefully this may help someone should you come across this issue which is pretty horrible.